# Python: using a class to handle method calls as if class attributes were method arguments

Tags: python

My hacked solution is below. I would greatly welcome comments.

---

I have a class which handles performance calculations for a given group of objects over a specified time frame (called `PerformanceAnalysisMixin`). And example would be:

```
class PerformanceAnalysisMixin(object):
    def set_time_frame(self, time_frame):
        sets up time frame and sources related info

    def return_over_time_frame(self, time_frame='past_year', values_only=False):
        return value if values_only else return ('ABC', values)

class Performance(object):
    # a mythical object which returns the values of calls to
    # PerformanceAnalyisMixin() as if they were properties
    # where the calls in are the form: name_for_method.arg0.arg1

>>> pam = PerformanceAnalysisMixin()
>>> pam.set_time_frame((2010, 2013))  # data for the past three years
>>> pam.return_over_time_frame('past_year', values_only=True)
0.13
>>> pam.return_over_time_frame('past_3_years', values_only=True)
0.25
```

I would like to be able to call the results, and not the method against a class instance, in a very idiomatic way. For example:

```
>>> perf = Performance(pam)
>>> # 'time_frame_return' is the name for the method 'return_over_time_frame'
>>> perf.time_frame_return.past_year
0.13
>>> perf.time_frame_return.past_3_years
0.25
```

If there were only a few methods and a few default time frames, this would be easy to hard code, but I would like enough abstraction so I don't need to code out many permutations. I would like to use attribute calls to specify the appropriate arguments for the ultimate method call.

I am looking for guidance here before I dive into creating this type of solution. I can pre-populate a dict if I wanted, but I'd rather have the method run when it's called on the fly.

My hacked solution:

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, name, fn=None):
        self.name = name
        self.arg_names = [self.name]
        self.fn = fn

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        self.key = F(key)
        self.arg_names.append(self.key.name)

        if key == 'res':
            _res = self.fn(*self.arg_names[:-1])
            self.res = _res
            return _res

        return self

>>> f = F('get', fn=(lambda a, b, c, d: (a, b, c, d)))
>>> r = f.some.more.stuff
>>> r.res
('get', 'some', 'more', 'stuff')
>>> g = F('one', fn=(lambda a, b, c, d: (a, b, c, d)))
>>> g.more.time.ftw.res
('one', 'more', 'time', 'ftw')
```

Comment: To clarify: `perf.time_frame_return.past_year` is _not_ a prestored value, but is the result of calculating `pam.return_over_time_frame('past_year',values_only=True)` on the fly? I'm not sure if you want to be caching results after they've been called with `pam` or if you want to be calculating them on the fly.

Comment: @gabe you are correct, `perf.time_frame_return.past_year` should be the result of calling the method rather than something calculated prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class MapProperty2Argument(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.fn(name)

class Performance(object):
    @property
    def time_frame_return(self):
        return MapProperty2Argument(
            PerformanceAnalysisMixin().return_over_time_frame)
```

Of course, you'll probably don't want to create the `PerformanceAnalysisMixin` object for each function call, but take some existing instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something along these lines :

```
class PamSugar(object):
    """ Here be dragons """
    def __init__(self, pam):
        self.pam = pam

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        # will be called if the key attribute is not found in usual places
        # http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

        # Better make sure key is allowed (you have to define the sanitizer)
        if not is_good_property_name(key):
            raise AttributeError("Can't handle that")

        return self.pam.return_over_time_frame(key, values_only=True)

class Performance(object):
    """ perf.sugar.past_year """
    def __init__(self, pam):
        self.sugar = PamSugar(pam)
```

Comment: So funny. I often will put in this snippet of code `else: assert False, "Here Be Dragons"`. I even thought Here Be Dragon Coding, LLC as my small company name.